# I have hidden worksheet but I can see the name of worksheet tabs on the saving page, how can I hide it complete?

Tags: excel, hidden, saving-data

I have hidden worksheet but I can see the name of worksheet tabs on the saving page, how can I hide it complete?

I blocked all the worksheet and protect it, I just left one worksheet available but all the hidden ones can be seen (at least the name of the worksheet) if you go and try to save the excel sheet.